# Stateful embedded library in Rust

Tags: rust, stateful, lazy-static, rust-no-std

I want to develop a library in Rust for microcontrollers that holds some state information.
This state data cannot be transferred to the caller of the library. I am using `#![no_std]`. The library should be suitable for bare metal applications and RTOS like Zephyr OS or FreeRTOS.
My approach so far was to use `lazy_static`:

```rust
use heapless::Vec;

lazy_static! {
    static ref nodes: Vec<u8, 100> = Vec::new();
}



fn foo(){
 nodes.push(1); 
}
```

This example doesn't compile. I am getting the following error:

```bash
cannot borrow data in dereference of `nodes` as mutable
trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `nodes`
```

Googling this error I fond out that a mutex is needed, see [link](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-can-i-use-mutable-lazy-static/3751). I don't know how to achieve this in `#![no_std]` code.

However more important is the question: What is the idiomatic way of handling global state when `#![no_std]` is used?

Comment: Global mutable state is generally not idiomatic. Can you provide more details on your use-case?

Comment: If you have to you can still use a `Mutex` just not a `std` one. The [spin](https://docs.rs/spin/latest/spin/index.html) crate provides synchronization primitives using a [Spinlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock).

Comment: Ideally, if you absolutely must have mutable global state, you would have the user provide the Mutex type. Then they can use something like [`cortex_m::interrupt::Mutex`](https://docs.rs/cortex-m/latest/cortex_m/interrupt/struct.Mutex.html)

Comment: @PitaJ: The use-case is a library that will run in secure world of a TrustZone-M device (Cortex-M23/33). The library will be called from the non-secure world. The mutable state is a secret that should not be accessible from the non-secure world. Can you explain how the user can provide the Mutex type?

Comment: Does the secret need to change during execution or do you just need to initialize it once?

Comment: Both. There are secrets that are constant but also secrets that need to change over time.